# jQuery hover event is not recognized

Tags: javascript, jquery, events

The below code works -

```
$("#x").hover(function() {
alert("hovered");
});
```

But the below code does not. Please explain why?

```
$("#x").on("hover", function() {
alert("hovered");
});
```

Note - #x is a button element. and the above code works for "click" event

Comment: You are using deprecated liabrary of JQuery

Comment: what's the version of jQuery you are using ?

Answer (score 3):

From jQuery [`.on()`'s documentation](http://api.jquery.com/on/):

> **Deprecated in jQuery 1.8, removed in 1.9**: The name `"hover"` used as a shorthand for the string `"mouseenter mouseleave"`. It attaches a single event handler for those two events, and the handler must examine `event.type` to determine whether the event is `mouseenter` or `mouseleave`. Do not confuse the `"hover"` pseudo-event-name with the `.hover()` method, which accepts one or two functions.

You could pass an object to the `on` method:

```
$("#x").on({
   mouseenter: function() {
     // ...
   },
   mouseleave: function() {
     // ...
   }
});
```

And if you want to delegate the events:

```
$('#aStaticParentOfX').on({
   mouseenter: function() {
     // ...
   },
   mouseleave: function() {
     // ...
   }
 }, "#x");
```

Answer (score 0):

Even the `.live()` has depricated from jQuery 1.9 if your version is below 1.9 you can use

```
$("#x").live("hover", function() {
    alert("hovered");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

try this..

```
$("#x").on("mouseover", function () {
     //wrire your code here
});
```

if you populated elements through javascript,use the following. It is replacement for deprecated jQuery.live.

```
$("body").on("mouseover","#x", function () {
     //wrire your code here
});
```

see this js fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/3aq48p5m/3/

Answer (score 0):

First: jQuery hover need 2 functions as arguments More here: http://api.jquery.com/hover/

```jquery
$('#x').hover(
    function() {
        // your 'mouseenter' event handle
    }, function() {
        // your 'mouseleave' event handle
});
```

Second: you can simply use CSS hover pseudo-class if your code operate on the same element (#x)

```css
#x:hover {
    // this will be added to #x when 'mouseenter', and remove when 'mouseleave'
    background-color: red;
}
```